# Retrieving data form Firebase database from current user

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

As mentioned in the title of this question, I'm trying to retrieve specific data from my firebase current user. In my android app I have a button called "view List" which creates a new fragment and inside the fragment I want to get the current user logged into firebase and get access to its saved location the user saved on the database. But I'm a bit confused on how to display all the saved locations from the database for the current user. I will post my code below and I will also post a screen shot of my current database on firebase.

[Click on this link for sreenshot of my database on Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6p8U.png)

```
case R.id.navigation_view_list:
          fragment = new ViewListFragment();
          fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.navigation_area, fragment);
          fragmentTransaction.commit();
          FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
          FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
          final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();
          myRef= myRef.child("Users").child(firebaseUser.getUid().toString()).child("Saved Location").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
          public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                   if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                         for(DataSnapshot userSavedLocation : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                              Log.d("savedLocation", userSavedLocation.getValue());
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                    // handle database Error
                            }
                        });

                        return true;
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about what the problem is?

Comment: I don't know how to display all the saved locations from the database for the current user. Sorry I wasn't being more specific. i have updated my question now

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();
      myRef= myRef.child("Users").child(user.getUid).child("Saved Location").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                     for(DataSnapshot userSavedLocation : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                          String key=userSavedLocation.getKey();
                          String location=userSavedLocation.child(key).getValue().toString();
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                // handle database Error
                        }
                    });
```

This may work, the idea is to get the random push key of each saved location, then use that key to get it's value.

Comment: Can you show us what                               Log.d("savedLocation", userSavedLocation.getValue()); returns?

Comment: why does it crash? What is the error? @rjimenez52 fix your db also remove the second user from the db

Answer (score 0):

@Peter Haddad's answer is correct however if you look a little closer at your DB you can notice that your data is not stored in the same manner. You have your first user WB...../saved location/locations. Where your second user d74.../saved location holds your data vs location objects within saved location. Then your third user reverts back to your first pattern: rpn..../saved location/locations.